# Is master more a release or a development branch?

Tags: git, branch

According to [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), the `master` only contains releases. However, on GitHub, the `master` branch looks more a development branch.

In Git's original concept, is the `master` more a *release* or a *development* branch? Should I expect my `master` branch to always build?

In [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133199/187938) very interesting answer it looks like `master` should not be a *production-ready* branch, but the default branch for most operations. This is not very compatible with the *git-flow*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Git's official documentation on branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)

> The “master” branch in Git is not a special branch. It is exactly like any other branch. The only reason nearly every repository has one is that the git init command creates it by default and most people don’t bother to change it.

In other words, master can be anything you want it to be. After Git was created though, some conventions and [workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/) started to appear which you are free to follow (or not).

Answer (score 1):

There is not such thing as "Git's original concept".

All git-flows are conventions people use for they own convenience.

Comment: So there is no large consensus around this?

Comment: @nowox I am not aware of such consensus. Although I think the first flow you mantioned in your post had big impact.